# MySQL left join unknown column

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I keep getting the error:

## 1054 - Unknown column 'A.AccomodationID' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT E.LastName, A.PUPoint, A.AccomodationID, P.pickup_Time, P.order_No
FROM ACCOMMODATION AS A, ENTITIES AS E
LEFT JOIN Pickup_Times AS P ON A.AccomodationID = P.AccomodationID
WHERE A.Entity_ID = E.Entity_ID
AND P.tour_ID = '11'
ORDER BY P.pickup_Time, P.order_No, E.LastName
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue as SQL joins are not my forte. I need to match the ACCOMMODATION and ENTITIES table as they combine vital information. I need to then left join a new table, the Pickup_Times table if this is at all possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your table is named `ACCOMMODATION` the field in your code is named `A.AccomodationID` (with one `m`). Have you checked if you have typed it correctly?

Comment: @AbcAeffchen I did a copy paste of col names. When I adopted this DB, that's how it was already spelled. lol. I did check that spelling however! I have already broken up the query into bite size chunks and they do work on their own

Comment: It looks like the table has no column with that name. I think we need more information to help you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AbcAeffchen I manage to resolve the issue. In the FROM section, I switched the order of ACCOMODATION and ENTITIES around and it's now working as expected.. I don't understand why it's working now

Comment: It is possible that MySQL first evaluates the `LEFT JOIN` and then the `JOIN` you made by the `,`. I always only use the `,` or I name what type of joins I want, but I never mix them up. Maybe you could have also resolve this by adding parentheses.

Comment: Yes I think putting it in parentheses will help in the future. Thank you for your help, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You may have it already solved based on the comments, but let me try to offer this to help you for future too.  Writing queries you have a mix of old from multiple tables comma separated and then adding a left-join.  I would strongly suggest putting the criteria on how the tables are joined together as JOIN clauses, don't blend as from/where.  Also, you added a left-join to your new pickup_times table, but then added an AND P.tour_id clause to the where which in essence converts it back to an INNER JOIN... meaning it will only return records that DO exist in the pickup times table.  Don't know if that is what you meant.

Here is a restructured query, also for readability nesting indentation to show the relation from table A-> B and B-> C (etc... as needed).  You can add both the criteria of the JOIN AND secondary conditions directly to the join clause, and add WHERE clause criteria based on your primary (first) table... something like.

```
SELECT 
      E.LastName, 
      A.PUPoint, 
      A.AccomodationID, 
      P.pickup_Time, 
      P.order_No
   FROM 
      ACCOMMODATION AS A
         JOIN ENTITIES AS E
            on A.Entity_ID = E.Entity_ID
         LEFT JOIN Pickup_Times AS P 
            ON A.AccomodationID = P.AccomodationID
            AND P.tour_ID = '11'
   ORDER BY 
      P.pickup_Time, 
      P.order_No, 
      E.LastName
```

By having the AND P.tour_id as part of the left-join condition, you can still get all accommodations regardless of a pickup time.  If you only want those WITH the specific pickup times AND tour = 11, just remove the "LEFT" portion of the join.

So, from the above indentation, you can see that both "Entities" and "Pickup_Times" are directly related to "Accommodations" and each of the aliases are respected.  Readability of queries is important both for you learning and writing, but for those following you to pickup where you may have left off.